# Why is this code making more threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I have a game, I've been developing for quite some time, here's is a preview:

Description of game:

-1 v 1

-Has sound

-etc...

[image]
/////
I have only 1 problem that needs to be fixed, and I can't quite seem to fix it.

Problem: Sound, whenever the players fire their weapons, the game plays the desired sound, but in doing so, creates more threads. I assume this is to make sure that the sound and the gameplay can run concurrently.

The additional thread count is evident, when I display the **Thread.activeCount()** method to the user(s).

When the game starts, the thread count is at 3, 1 for default main thread, 1 for another thread starting in a constructor and another supposedly started from clicking on the JMenuBar.

Here's the change in thread count:

When game is first started.

[image: Before] 
After lasers fired.

[image: After lasers fired]
After players have fired lasers, this cause sound to be played (which then seems to be the culprit of additional thread creation).

Here's the code that makes the laser firing sound, whenever a person presses a 
certain button on the keyboard.

```
private void playClip() { //called when player fires lasers
        Clip clip;
        AudioInputStream auIn = null;
        try {
            auIn = ai; //instance variable 'ai' initialized in constr
            ai = null; //'ai' is AudioInputStream object, which used an URL
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
            clip.open(auIn);
            clip.start();
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
            err.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            Logger.getLogger(OuterSpace.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (auIn != null) {
                try {
                    auIn.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    err.println(ex);
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    Logger.getLogger(OuterSpace.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

        try { //for some reason, i have to reinitialize, in order to hear
        //the sounds again, note again, 'ai' is AudioInputStream, also
        //'url' is the URL where the sound file is at.
            this.ai = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.url);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException ex) {
            err.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            Logger.getLogger(OuterSpace.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

My main question is: why does this sound code above create more threads, and why are these threads not 'removed'. Suggestions and tips are welcome!!! Thank You. (sorry about confusing formatting!)

Comment: How many times do you create a `Clip`?

Comment: As many times the players press the fire key.

Comment: You might want to have someway to dispose of any prexisting clips or clips which are no longer playing...

Comment: I tried setting the clip to null and closing it, yet the thread count rises anyways.

Comment: So, in my "quick" test, for each `Clip` that I created, it created a thread to play it.  You may need a pool of `Clip`s for a sound, which you can pull from and re-use as well as manage (down sizing the pool if the sounds are not used after a period of time)

Comment: Are you calling `stop` and `close` on the `Clip`?  In my testing it cleaned up the `Thread`s just fine for me...

Comment: I called close and set the clip to null.

Comment: In you code sniippet, you don't close the `Clip`, you close the stream, since `Clip` is local variable, it's not possible for you to do anywhere else...

Comment: Perhaps you should use a `LineListener` to detect when the clip stops and `stop`, `flush` and `close` it then, this should free up it's underlying resources (like the stream) and the thread